# SQL Server is 2 hours delayed than my current time

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, ssms

This is a SQL database on Azure:

[Time in SQL Server vs my time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Me1nH.png)

I'm trying to execute `SELECT GETDATE()` and it shows the date 2 hours later than my current time.

I tried to check the time zone in SQL Server and it shows '**(UTC) Coordinated Universal Time**'. Is there any solution for SQL Server to show the right time when I know the zone that I'm in?

Comment: er yeah, you convert it to your timezone .... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/at-time-zone-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Date and time functiona return the time according to the host, not the client, in SQL. Normally.it would be up to the presentation layer to take that time and convert it to the client's local time.

Comment: All cloud services, no matter the vendor, are UTC  as that's the only thing that makes sense. While you can change the timezone of AzureSQL, a *far* better option is to *not* use local time. There's no single local time in a cloud application where the end users may come from anywhere. Most web apps store time as `datetimeoffset` or UTC and let the UI convert it to the end user's locale

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper solution is not to change the Database time zone,

instead, you should just convert any time to your local time, like this:

```
SELECT  SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() AT TIME ZONE 'E. Europe Standard Time'
```